# что такое Proxy Object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

что такое proxy object в Hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate автоматически генерирует для ваших классов с данными наследников, которые перехватывают get-методы для реализации ленивой загрузки и set-методы для отслеживания изменений.

Эти классы называются proxy-классами, а их экземпляры - proxy-объектами.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае прокси-объект - это объект, который служит посредником для доступа к другому объекту, каким-то образом меняя свойства или поведение этого объекта.

Так что со стороны клиента (т.е. объекта-пользователя) поведение выглядит несколько не так, как было бы при непосредственном доступе.

Используется также в случаях, когда прямой доступ к используемому объекту по какой-то причине невозможен. 
См. подробнее:

[Википедия: Заместитель_(шаблон_проектирования)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

или в книге

[Э. Гамма, Р. Хелм и др. Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования (aka "Gang of Four")](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/)